# Need help with understanding a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

[image]

Can someone please explain to me why $y_0 (x) = 1$ when $\alpha = 0$ and $y_1 (x) = x$ when $\alpha = 1$... $y_0 (x) = 1 - 2x^2$ when $\alpha = 2$ and so on. I understand that subbing in those values creates a $0$ factor. But how do they simplify to those polynomials? Wouldn't it just be the sum of $0$'s? ie $\sum 0$?

Comment: By convention, when $m=0$, the product $$(0^2-a^2)(2^2-a^2)\cdots((2m-2)^2-a^2)=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}((2k)^2-a^2)$$ which is the empty product, is always equal to $1$, even if $a=0$. The same applies to the products in $y_1$.

Comment: Ahhh that makes more sense. Thank you @Did